# extend('PagerDefault') doesn't call pager_default_initialize

Tags: database

My code:

```
   $num_per_page = 1;

   $query = db_select('redagavimas', 'r')
      ->fields("r");
   $query->join('dusers', 'd', 'd.id = r.user');
   $query->join('companies', 'c', 'c.id = r.company');
   $query->join('documents', 'doc', 'doc.id = r.doc');

   $query->addField('d', 'name');
   $query->addField('d', 'surname');
   $query->addField('c', 'name', 'company');
   $query->addField('c', 'id', 'companyID');
   $query->addField('doc', 'name', 'docname');
   $query->addField('r', 'user', 'did');

   $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit($num_per_page);
   $query->extend('TableSort')->orderByHeader($header);

   ....

   $result = $query->execute();

   ....

     '#suffix' => theme('pager', array( 'tags' => array())),
```

I don't see any pager; If I call somewhere `pager_default_initialize()`, then I see the pager. What I did wrong?

**EDIT :**

I try:

```
echo $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit($num_per_page)->getCountQuery();
```

and get query, which `return >100` rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As documented on the See the [Extenders](http://drupal.org/node/508796) page on drupal.org:

> To use an extender, you must first have a query object. From the query object, the extend() method will return a new object that should be used in place of the query object. For example:

```
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault');
```

> The above line takes a select query, creates a new PagerDefault query object that contains the original select query, and returns the new object. $query may now be used as if it were the original query object but with additional methods now available.
>
> Note that $query is not altered in place. The new object is returned from extend(), and if it is not saved to a variable it will be lost. For example, the following will not do what you expect:

So, you first line should looks like:

```
$query = db_select('redagavimas', 'r')->extend('PagerDefault')->fields("r");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to print the theme function like this:

```
print theme('pager', array('tags' => array());
```